# Как лучше всего хранить Context?

Tags: android, java

Очень часто приходится использовать `Context` вне класса `Activity` (например, при использовании б/д). Как его лучше хранить? `getApplicationContext()` использовать нельзя.
Пробовал хранить в статическом поле специально заведенного класса, но мне сказали, это чревато утечкой памяти.
Есть мысль каждый класс наследовать от `Context`, и там использовать `getApplicationContext()`, но намного ли это будет лучше  хранения в статиках?
Какой способ решения предлагаете Вы?

Answer (score 4):

1. Хранить `Context/Activity` вообще не советую - это чревато утечкой памяти
2. Самый лучший способ это создать собственный класс `Application` - сделать его [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) и брать Context через `Application.getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 0):

Передавать в конструктор

Answer (score 0):

Как обычную переменную экземпляра класса, но не статическую. Просто пишите везде, где он нужен(в методах, в конструкторе) первым параметром контекст и потом вызывая свой код передаете ему текущий контекст - контекст активити в котором вызываете свой код. А лучше вообще не хранить его как переменную, ибо часто сохранение контекста вообще не нужно. Исключение могут составить адаптеры, вынесенные во внешние классы.