# Как использовать контексты (Context) в приложении и не бояться NPE?

Tags: android, context

Для примера использую 3 активности: SplashActivity, LoginActivity, MainActivity. В каждой из них использую элементы, в которых требуются **контексты** (Toast, методы внешних классов, методы текущего Activity и т.д.).

Допустим, если использовать Тосты внутри приложения, то здесь все по старинке:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Current activity toast", Toast.SHORT).show();
```

Но что если, допустим, необходимо использовать Тосты вне активности? Допустим в каком либо внешнем классе.
*Первое* что заметил, люди обычно передают в параметр метода Context и **делать проверку контекста на null** в самом методе. Но, как мне кажется, этот способ не решает весь вопрос.
И *второе*, это **вызов контекста приложения** (*getApplicationContext()*) во внешнем классе.

Поэтому, возник такой вопрос... Лучше всего привязываться к каждому отдельному контексту (отдельно взятой Activity) или создать один глобальный контекст и использовать его во всем приложении? [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/126825/203270) человек говорит о том что лучше всего сделать синглтон и брать его так:

```
Application.getApplicationContext();
```

Можете поделиться своим опытом использования контекстов в своих проектах с минимальным риском получения NPE? Буду рад вашим пожеланиям.

P.S. Да, можно использовать Dagger 2 и радоваться жизни, но интересует именно решение данного вопроса "в лоб".

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю реализацию с сиглтоном в виде applicationContext вполне приемлимой. Самой реальной проблемой связанной с таким подходом будет проблема unit тестирования. Я знаю некоторые разработчики выделяют проблемы связанные с нарушением инкапсуляции и нарушением закона Деметры, я считаю в контексте данной задачи говорить о таких вещах нет смысла.

Использовать везде applicationContext не стоит (все таки между контекстами есть разница). В рамках представлений которые относятся к конкретной активити вполне можно использовать активити контекст. А ваш пример с выводом Toast вне активити это довольно странная задача, лучше вернуть информацию (например ошибку) в активити и там отобразить ваш Toast чем взаимодействовать с ui не пойми откуда.

Comment: неплохо было бы добавить, что беспорядочное использование контекстов разных уровней - первая причина утечек памяти

Comment: Окей, с тостами во внешнем классе погарячился. Допустим, сейчас у меня есть класс не связанный с Activity (NetworkHelper). В нем есть один единственный метод статический метод isConnected, в котором идет проверка подключения к сети. Этот метод используется часто и везде и в нем необходим контекст. Я так понимаю, здесь нужно использовать getApplicationContext из класса синглтона? И опять же, меня преследует мания крашей в виде NPE, хотя знаю что ApplicationContext живет на протяжении всего ЖЦ приложения, а не Activity....